# For some request I need to get latency, connection time and page rendering time using Jmeter

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

In jmeter view results table latency amd connection time values are showing 0 milli second only.. could you please tell me how to get actual latency, rendering time and connection time values using jmeter

Expected results:
Get latency
Get Connection time
Get page rendering time

Answer (score 0):

For [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler value `0` for the Connect Time is connected with [Connection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Connection) header with the value of [`Keep-Alive`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Keep-Alive)

Real browser establishes the connection once and it's kept open at least for the first iteration that's why you're seeing the connection time metric only for the first request. So it is kind of expected and you might want to take some extra steps in order to [configure JMeter to behave like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser).

If you need to mimic different behaviour:

1. In the HTTP Request sampler untick `Use KeelAlive` box:

   [image]
2. In the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) untick `Same user on each iteration` box.

   [image]

When it comes to "rendering time" - you won't be able to get it using HTTP Request sampler, as per [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. **Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does** (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

So if you want to have page rendering time you will need to go for i.e. [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/)

Comment: Thank you for your help.Could you please tell me how to get rendering time and latency using Webdriver sampler..